# (iOS) Simultaneously auto-shrink 2 labels that have constraints to each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

### Setup:

I have 2 labels set up like this:

[image: Labels, before autoshrink]

**Orange Containing View:**

- Fixed width and height

**Left Label:**

- Top, left, and bottom constraints == 8 to *Orange View*
- Right constraint >= 8 to *Right Label*
- Horizontal Content Hugging is unchanged (251)
- Horizontal Compression Resistance is unchanged (750)
- Auto-shrink font to minimum scale of 0.5

**Right Label:**

- Top, right, and bottom constraints == 8 to *Orange View*
- Left constraint >= 8 to *Left Label*
- Horizontal Content Hugging is unchanged (251)
- Horizontal Compression Resistance is unchanged (750)
- Auto-shrink font to minimum scale of 0.5

---

### What I want to happen:

When the label texts become longer, BOTH labels' fonts shrink together to a minimum font scale (or size) before truncating.

---

### What's actually happening:

Only 1 label's font auto-shrinks and then truncates, and I get a constraint complaint about needing to make 1 of the label's Compression Resistance higher than the other. Even when satisfying that constraint, both labels' fonts won't auto-shrink.

[image: Labels, after autoshrink]

---

### Question:

Is there any way, through autolayout or code, to get both of the labels' fonts to first shrink, and then both truncate if needed? Thanks.

Comment: I think that might not be possible, maybe you can try one label and do the text formatting something similar to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Using Xcode 9.2 autolayout, this works automatically for me.

I have the two labels in a view. This view is constrained to a UITableViewCell.

Left Label:

- leftLabel.top = top
- leftLabel.leading = leading
- leftLabel.bottom = bottom
- rightLabel.trailing = leftLabel.trailing + 8
- leftLabel hugging priority = ( 251, 251 )
- leftLabel compression resistance priority = ( 750, 750 )
- font is size 20, autoshrink set to minimum font size of 12
- number of lines for label = 1

Right Label:

- rightLabel.trailing = leftLabel.trailing + 8
- rightLabel.top = top
- rightLabel.trailing = trailing
- rightLabel.bottom = bottom
- rightLabel hugging priority = ( 252, 251 )
- rightLabel compression resistance priority = ( 750, 750 )
- font is size 20, autoshrink set to minimum font size of 12
- number of lines for label = 1

When the text strings for labelLeft and labelRight are short, the space between them is large. When those strings are long, the space between them is small (nearly exactly 8) and both fonts have shrunk, equally.

Comment: did you meant in Right Label: `rightLabel.leading = leftLabel.trailing + 8` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add *left label* width equals *right label* width constraint

Comment: Well, I want both labels' font sizes to shrink (and as a consequence, their widths), but I don't want to force them to be the same width. So this won't work in my instance.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible by just using autolayout constraints. One thing you can do is as follows:

1. Set the Autoshrink to Fixed Font Size for both the labels.
2. Have two font sizes (minFontSize and maxFontSize) between which it is OK for the texts to be rendered with.
3. Concatenate both the texts and find the font size (calculatedFontSize) that is needed for the concatenated text to fit the available width. You can refer it [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1619903-sizewithfont).

To calculate the available width, use the following:
`availableWidth = width(orangeView) - leftSpace - rightSpace - betweenSpace`

For your instance: leftSpace is 8, rightSpace is 8, betweenSpace is 8.

4. Your target fontSize, targetFontSize = min(max(calculatedFontSize, minFontSize), maxFontSize)
5. Now, apply the target font to the two labels.